# How to create API with Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, api-design

I am currently creating a Flutter plugin, but I'm stuck in creating API. 
This is an API that I want to create. (Java Example)

JAVA

```
    PeterWorks.UserProperties userProperties = new PeterWorks.UserProperties();
        userProperties.setAttrs("user_nick", "peterPark")
        .setAttrs("place","Seoul")
        .setAttrs("height",180)
        .setAttrs("married",false);
```

Can you give me a sample that how to create that API with Dart?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear. show more code. what is the use of that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the types of [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that are normally allowed here, as this is borderline and others my outright flag it. In general, you should be posting specific questions showing what you've actually tried and not "build it for me" questions.

That said, [here](https://pusher.com/tutorials/backend-developer-part-2) is a link (no affiliation) I referenced a while ago that focuses on building a basic backend server using Dart. See the second example.

Comment: Thanks for the command. I will keep that in mind when I write a question next time. and again thanks for the reference too.